# Check connection to IP address from local HTML via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, connection

quick background

I'm making a map in HTML out of SVGs of the office I work in. I have the locations of the printers in the office, and planned on using the map to 1) show new users where their printers are and 2) be able to quickly see if the printers are all online. I would like to do more(possibly check toner levels), but that's a task for another day maybe. Anyway, I'm trying to figure out if the locally running HTML file can somehow try to connect in some way to the printer's known IP address. If it can connect, then clearly it is online, and if not, well... then it isn't.

So my question is: How do I connect to a networked printer via Javascript to verify that it is online?

I've tried using an iframe to load the printers webpage, but I can't look at it to see anything about it because my page is using the file protocol, and the printers page is using http. I could go that way, but I have no idea if I can even see if the iframe loaded successfully or not.

I've also tried the Image method, where you use the ip address as the image src, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: the printers use http, which sounds like it might serve html at the address. if that html has an img, you can find the url of the image and check for that image file working or error-ing out. you don't set the printer's url to the img src, you set an img url from the printer's page to the img src.

Comment: Thanks, the only issue is that I'm trying to do this with multiple printers of varying models and brands, so I can't guarantee that there will be a picture to grab every time.